Can't use my library classes after importing via Gradle or Maven
I have a library that I loaded via Jitpack. My build.gradle in the library project looks like this:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.nickname'
version = '1.0.4'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId = 'com.nickname'
            artifactId = 'library'
            version = '1.0.4'
        }
    }
}

def targetJavaVersion = 17
java {
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(targetJavaVersion)
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    if (JavaVersion.current() < javaVersion) {
        toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(targetJavaVersion)
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    if (targetJavaVersion >= 10 || JavaVersion.current().isJava10Compatible()) {
        options.release = targetJavaVersion
    }
}

processResources {
    def props = [version: version]
    inputs.properties props
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
}

jar {
    archiveFileName = 'Library.jar'
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

Overall, the library is successfully uploaded to Jitpack and I get an example for adding a dependency, for example implementation 'com.github.nickname:Library:1.0.4'. The point is that after adding my dependency to other projects, I run into a situation where I can't interact with classes from my library. However, I can see in the “External Libraries” tab that my library is indeed loaded via gradle, this library has all the necessary classes, but I can't interact with them. If I open any class in my library, I get this error:
Java file outside source root
I suspect that the error is exactly at the point of building my library and with Jitpack, because the other dependencies I add via gradle work fine. How can I fix this?
I've already tried reloading the Gradle/Maven project, but in both cases I get this error. I also searched for something on 'Java file outside source root', but the advice from there doesn't help in my situation.

Okay, I fixed it, the error was in specifying
group = 'com.nickname'
version = '1.0.4'
in build.gradle. If you remove that, everything works correctly.

If you think other people may be experiencing a similar problem and you think that your solution may help them, then post an actual answer rather than a comment.
